# SwiftUI fullscreen horizontal swipe with dot indicator

Tags: swiftui, scrollview

Many apps have an intro view that has fullscreen pages with a dot indicator at the bottom. Sometimes it is used to gather same basic information, sometimes to introduce the app features.

How can I realize that?
I tried the ScrollView with a horizontal setting. The issue is to set up the content to fit the screen and have the edges snap on scroll. Second issue is the have a dotted indicator that highlights the current page.

Comment: For dots: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipagecontrol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to wrap UIPageControl with UIViewControllerRepresentable.

Comment: Looks complicated. Thought about something simple like  `PageView { PageOneView() PageTwoView() }`. But your answer helps, though. Thank you.